# How do I reduce the latency in sendto?

Tags: embedded-linux, latency, sendto

I am running an embedded linux system, streaming 6Mbps of UDP data to a known single point destination.  I use sendto to send the data.  What I have noticed is that although I can monitor the time between calls to sendto and when specific data is being sent out, when that data arrives at the other end then the time between those marked packets is very different.  eg before it's sent, the interval between marked packets varies between 8ms and 35ms.  When it arrives, the interval between marked packets varies between 8ms and 100ms.

So I'm sure the problem lies in how linux then deals with the data before it is sent out on the ethernet.  Can anyone explain what happens after sendto before the data actually reaches the PHY?  Can anyone help with how to reduce the latency that seems to appear here?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you sure the bottleneck is in the Linux stack? More often it is in the network speed. What's your CPU usage? What's the LAN link speed? 100 Mb/s? 1 Gb/s? Do you have a direct cable or is there any switch/router in between? Other devices use the same LAN? Does it go through the internet? What is the packet size and the average time between two *consecutive* packets?

Comment: Also: what type of device sends the data? (CPU, board, etc) And what type of device receives the data?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  It's currently a 1 Gb/s LAN, and not going over the internet/WAN.  The packet sizes are between 200 bytes and 1500 bytes.  Time between consecutive packets varies but can be as little as 20 microseconds and as much as 5 milliseconds.  The device sending the data is an ARM CPU through a 1Gb PHY.  The device receiving the data is a PC with an i7 CPU.

Comment: Is there other traffic on the LAN? What is the ARM CPU average load? Is the ARM CPU doing other work that can make it busy and respond slowly? What kind of ARM (Cortex-Axx? MHz? Number of cores?). Keep in mind normal IP networks do never guarantee latency or other performance values. Yet, without other traffic, packets generally should leave and arrive with very similar timings.

Comment: Can you capture a few packets at the sender (using tcpdump) and *the same* packets at the receiver (using wireshark or tcpdump) and send a side-by-side comparison of the timings?